# Missing 'post_id' column and relationships between users/posts/comments in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many, belongs-to, relationships

I'm still familiarizing myself with Rails and have a question in regards to a problem I'm trying to solve utilizing Rails 3.2. Here is a link to the few files in question where I assume my problem lies:

https://gist.github.com/0fe5cf9093b21f4f632f

I apologize if the code is really bad/adds a few things that don't need to exist as I'm still trying to get used to how everything works as I go along.

I want to have comments for each post that is made on my website - and the logic I have is that users have many comments, and I suppose that the posts have many comments through the users. I do have that relationship added (though it doesn't seem to be doing anything in particular), and I feel as if all of my table references are correct (though I haven't added anything to users as I'm using devise and didn't feel like I needed to add anything as the post is a separate object itself).

As of right now, I can show all of the comments in general, as in I am able to create and save them. I was also saving, at the very least, the `user_id` variable, so it can understand which account is making the comment. I'm not really sure where/when I should be passing in the `post_id`, so that's the biggest issue. Any way I've tried to do it in the `posts_controller` (since in theory I should be able to edit that attribute when the post page is loaded), I get an

```
undefined method 'post_id'
```

or

```
no post_id column
```

error, indicating that it doesn't exist, even though as far as I understand, I've defined it. The fact that the `user_id` is able to be saved, as mentioned before, further confuses me.

If I show the attributes on a comment created in my show view, I get the following:

```
{
    "id"=>1,
    "content"=>"text here",
    "posted"=>Sat, 03 Nov 2012 20:36:53 UTC +00:00,
    "user_id"=>1,
    "created_at"=>Sat, 03 Nov 2012 20:36:53 UTC +00:00,
    "updated_at"=>Sat, 03 Nov >2012 20:36:53 UTC +00:00
}
```

There is no `post_id`, although I did add it into the migration table for comments. Trying to pass the `@post.id` in the posts controller (to a show method's instance of a comment, as it would be available beneath a post) gives a mass assignment error. Messing around with the `:class` and `:foreign_key` options hasn't done much, either. Based on the research I have done, which includes some of Rails' own documentation, I don't believe I need a `has_many` through relationship, but I don't know where I'm missing what I need to have the information save accordingly.

Perhaps this is all due in part to my lacking understanding of database/model relationship design, although any help is appreciated. I have seen a couple of similar questions but I still find it difficult to apply their solutions to the context of my own particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post, it sounds like you may have added post_id to the migration after you created the table.  If this is true, please understand that it is bad practice to modify a migration file.  Instead, you should create a new migration that will "fix" the status of your database.

It looks like your relationships are setup correctly for posts and comments.  The model with "belongs_to" will have the foreign key; as such, I would expect comments to have "post_id."

Please see if the following works for you:

1. Remove the "post_id" addition to your already-run comments migration file.
2. Create a new migration:  `rails g migration addPostIdToComments`
3. In the generated migration, enter this in the "change" method: `add_column :comments, :post_id, :integer`
4. Run your migrations: "rake db:migrate"

This should add the post_id column to your comments table.

If you get in a bind and want to completely destroy your database and recreate it from scratch (it looks like a sample application), (**please note this will completely drop the database**) you may run: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

The mass assignment issue may be related to a new security option in rails which requires whitelisting all model attributes (columns) that can be updated in the database.  Please see the attr_accessible documentation for whitelisting attributes: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Welcome to rails!  Hope this helps!

Comment: I suppose I was a bit of an idiot and the database wipe (considering the stage I'm at, it's fine to do) fixed the issue of post_id showing up. My issue right now is that I'm not sure of where to necessarily set the value of post_id to the current post's id; simply using "@comment.post_id = @post.id" doesn't appear to be doing the trick, as it's remaining as nil. Maybe I simply have to work around it using the mass assignment whitelisting, but I feel that there should be a better solution I haven't found.

Comment: Apparently simply making :post_id attr_accessible in comment.rb fixed the problem. I have to add "<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => params[:id] %>" in the show model, which probably isn't the best solution, but at least it works for now until I figure out something better.